# SQLite return value incorrect

Tags: android, sqlite

The following is my implementation of a function to get details of a professor,building,room,floor,subject,time from a table.

```
public List<NewButton> getAllTimingButtons(String building_name,String floor_name,String room_name) {

       List<NewButton> button_list = new LinkedList<NewButton>();

       //build the query
       String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TimingTable;

       //get reference to writable DB
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);


       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           do {

               NewButton button = new NewButton();


               button.setBuildingName(cursor.getString(1));
               button.setFloorName(cursor.getString(2));
               button.setRoomName(cursor.getString(3));
               button.setTime(cursor.getString(4));
               button.setProfName(cursor.getString(5));
               button.setSubjName(cursor.getString(6));

               if(button.getBuildingName().equals(building_name) 
                       && button.getFloorName().equals(floor_name)
                       && button.getRoomName().equals(room_name))
               {
                    button_list.add(button);
                    Log.d("get timings",button.getProfName()+" "+button.getSubjName());
               }
           } while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }
       db.close();
       return button_list;
   }
```

This is my table

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TimingTable+" ("+TimingId+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
              BuildingName+" TEXT, "+FloorName+" TEXT, "+RoomName+ " TEXT, "+
             Time+" TEXT, "+ProfessorName+" TEXT, "+SubjectName+" TEXT )");
```

The problem is that my return list contains only the last added button detail twice. My debu g log shows that the table was holding the values correctly. I can do something like return a string list with the values added in order and reading three at a time but I want to know what the error is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use your column index to get the value of each one from your cursor.
Something like this :

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TimingId));
...
```

regards